# How do I check if a child node does not exist?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have to create an xslt to have a crossover for 2 different xsd-files, so that one version can match the other. 
I have an element with children where some children are optional. In this case. Test 3 is optional.

```
<Test1>
    <TestA>data</TestA>
    <TestB>data</TestB>
    <TestC>data</TestC>
</Test1>
<Test2>
    <TestA>data</TestA>
    <TestC>data</TestC>
</Test2>
```

Now i want to see if Testb exists and if not, i have to add it in the right place (between Testa and Testc). 
Note that Test1 is already a child of some other element and I 'contact' each element  with a xsl:for-each.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether an element exists, you can use `xsl:if` or `xsl:when`
with respective `test="element_name"`.

An example script performing your task can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[matches(name(),'[a-z]+\d+','i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="curr" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="('A','B','C')">
        <xsl:variable name="childName" select="concat('Test',.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="elem" select="$curr/*[name() = $childName]"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$childName}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$elem">
              <xsl:value-of select="$elem"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>Surrogate value for </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main part is a template matching an element, which name consists of
letters (at least one) and then digits (again at least one).

Then `curr` variable is needed to keep the *current element*, because
`for-each` loop changes it, but we still need a reference to the
**outer** current element.

`For-each` loop arranges processing of any child *Test...* element,
with name ending in `A`, `B` or `C`.

If the required child element exists, its value is printed, otherwise
the script prints a respective surrogate value.

Probably this is not the final version you need, but at least you have
some starting point to create your final version.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to fix the problem using your code and a little bit of adjustments to it!